# I am writing sql select query results to csv using php file but why am I getting different order of saved data in csv file?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am writing my `SQL` query's data to CSV file row by row. I ran the SQL query in **`phpmyadmin`** and its returning data as per required order i.e., master's table records 1st and then the child's in a row. But when I executed a similar query via `PHP` script then the saved CSV file is not showing in the exact order in which **`phpmyadmin`** was showing the results.
The script that I have written so far is:

```
<?php 

    function getColumnNames($conn, $table_name) {
        $select_column_names_q = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '".$table_name."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $select_column_names_q);
        $columns_array = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $columns_array[] = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
        }
        return $columns_array;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['export'])) {
        include "dbconfig.php";
        $master_table = $_POST['dbMasterTable'];
        $child_table = $_POST['dbChildTable'];
        $sql_q_export = "SELECT * FROM ".$master_table." as m_t, ".$child_table." as c_t WHERE m_t.urn = c_t.urn;";
        $all_data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_q_export);
        
        $master_tbl_columns = getColumnNames($conn, $master_table);
        $child_tbl_columns = getColumnNames($conn, $child_table);
        $header_fields = array_merge($master_tbl_columns, $child_tbl_columns);

        //create a file pointer
        $fp = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
        // set column headers
        $delimiter = ",";
        $filename = "members_" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";
        header("Content-Type:application/csv"); 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');    
        header('Expires: 0');

        fputcsv($fp, $header_fields, $delimiter);
        while ($data_row = mysqli_fetch_array($all_data)) {
            fputcsv($fp, array_values($data_row), $delimiter);
        }

        // //move back to beginning of file
        fseek($fp, 0);
        fpassthru($fp);
        fclose($fp) or die("Can't close php://output");
    }
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Unless you specifically put an ORDER BY in your SQL then the database is not under any obligation to provide the data in the same order every time.

Comment: Sorry if my statement is confusing. Can we control the order of the columns?  E.g., the problem I am facing is that row-1's urn is in 1st column and after 82nd column second tables column start from 83rd column and at 87th there is another urn(matching one) which is from the second table. When i store the data to csv and download there is some other data in that matching URN's column.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution to my problem. I hope it will be helpful for others in the future.

```
<?php     
    if (isset($_POST['export'])) {
        include "dbconfig.php";
        $master_table = $_POST['dbMasterTable'];
        $child_table = $_POST['dbChildTable'];
        $sql_q_export = "SELECT * FROM ".$master_table." as m_t, ".$child_table." as c_t WHERE m_t.urn = c_t.urn2;";    

        // create empty variable to be filled with export data
        $csv_export = '';

        // query to get data from database

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_q_export);
        $field = mysqli_field_count($conn);

        // create line with field names
        for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
            $csv_export.= mysqli_fetch_field_direct($query, $i)->name.',';
        }

        // newline (seems to work both on Linux & Windows servers)
        $csv_export.= '
        ';

        // loop through database query and fill export variable
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            // create line with field values
            for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
                $csv_export.= ''.$row[mysqli_fetch_field_direct($query, $i)->name].',';
            }
            $csv_export.= '
        ';
        }

        $csv_filename = "members_" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";

        // Export the data and prompt a csv file for download
        header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$csv_filename."");
        echo($csv_export);
    }
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Glad you solved it. But it would help others a lot more if you edit your answer to explain specifically what you did to solve it, as well as just providing a dump of the code